# Do not change order when switching windows

Tags: navigation

Suppose I have 3 applications running - Firefox, Terminal and Spotify in that order.
Currently, I have my Firefox open. When I hold alt and tab once, I reach Terminal.

[image]

I am at the terminal window now. When I try to switch windows from there, I see the following order.

[image]

**I want the order to not change.** To be precise, considering the first image as starting point again, when I alt+tab once to the terminal. I want my order in the windows switcher to be, in my left it should have firefox, in the middle terminal, which is my currently active window since I alt+tab once, and in the right spotify.

Is that possible? If yes, then how?